# How can I implement an OF  file chooser with php?

Tags: php, filechooser

I need to implement an OS file chooser with php but I don't know how to go about doing this.
Can somebody guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Too vague. What is your specific problem? If you're asking about architecture you need to provide more details about what a 'fileChooser' is and what its expected to do. Otherwise the documentation does just fine [Google PHP File Upload](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a basic file choosing form.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> 
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the basic php to handle the form.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
  {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
  }
```

You can read more here.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: yes, but I could have very well linked to php.net and gotten very similar code with same insecure structure.  w3schools is a reference site, and should be used as one, not use of code line for line people still need to learn security practices.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using php to drive a desktop application, use the method of your UI toolkit, such as [`GTKFileChooser`](http://gtk.php.net/manual/en/gtk.gtkfilechooser.php).

If you're using php to serve webpages, note that the server can only send HTML and JavaScript to the client, and not natively open webpages. Use an `<input>` element in your HTML code:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="your-script.php" method="POST">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

You can submit the form automatically from JavaScript with the [`submit` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.submit). If you place the whole form in an [iframe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-iframe-element.html), you can do so in the background.

For details on the input field, consult the [HTML5 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#file-upload-state). For information on how to handle the file once the form is submitted, have a look at the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).